# Preg_match regex

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Can anyone help with the correct preg_match regex thank You!
I just want to extract the complete url:s containing the "thumb4" text, but with my regex
I also get the "thumb1" url:s Like below:

```
http://assets-edge.mysite.com/assets/properties/2013/10/03/38810/thumb4_bed_5_wp1.jpg

http://assets-edge.mysite.com/assets/properties/2015/08/10/38810/thumb1_bath_4_wp1.jpg
```

My regex:

```
"#http://assets-edge.mysite.com/assets/properties/.+?thumb4.+?\.(jpg)#is"
```

Comment: Both of them consisting `thumb4` `url's` only

Comment: Sorry did paste the wrong link, one of the should be http://assets-edge.mysite.com/assets/properties/2015/08/10/38810/thumb1_bath_4_wp1.jpg

Comment: You regex works pretty fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @Kenneth: Are you looking for [this](http://ideone.com/mhSTBp)?